# Fetching all columns of a row into collection in StoredProcedure

Tags: oracle

I have fetched a single row into a rowType variable. this row has 80 columns.So, I do not 
want to hard code column names in my program and fetching column names from data dictionary.

Please someone tell me, how can I access indivisual column values?????
following is my code.

```
DECLARE
fetchedRow EMP%ROWTYPE;
TYPE columnNameList IS TABLE OF USER_TAB_COLUMNS.column_name%TYPE;
CURSOR empCursor IS select column_name from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name = 'EMP';
empColumnNames columnNameList;
colName varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    -- Fetching column names of EMP from data dictionary
    OPEN  empCursor;
    FETCH empCursor BULK COLLECT INTO empColumnNames;
    CLOSE empCursor;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Columns fetched');

BEGIN
    SELECT * into fetchedRow from EMP where EMP_ID = 1234;
END;

colName := 'fetchedRow.'||empColumnNames(1);   --- colName will have fetchedRow.EMP_ID
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Going to Compare'||colName);

--stuck here
     if colName = 1234 then  -- Want to compare value of fetchedRow.EMP_ID with 1234
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Matching');
    else
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not-Matching');
    END IF;  
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error'||SQLERRM);

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a dynamic SQL to access field that way, but one little trick is to place current row to some place accessible from SQL statement, for example package header.

Tom Kyte good as always, look [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2170326695312).

SQL fidlle with live example can be found [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eca68/4).

Some code for illustration:

Declare package header

```
create or replace package TmpRowAccess as 

  CurRow emp%rowtype;

end;
```

When fetching rows - fetch it into package variable

```
SELECT * into TmpRowAccess.CurRow from EMP where rownum = 1;
```

Construction for access field values

```
  declare 
    vRes char(1);
    vParam number := 1234;
  begin

    execute immediate 
      '
        begin 
          if(:1 = TmpRowAccess.CurRow.'|| colName ||') then 
            :2 := ''Y''; 
          else 
            :2 := ''N''; 
          end if; 
        end;
      '
      using in vParam, out vRes;

    if(vRes = 'Y') then 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Matching');
    else
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not-Matching');
    end if;

  end;
```